# How to do reactor kafka consumer configuration for two consumer model classes in application properties file?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

```
I have two consumer model classes:
1. EventConsumerModel. java
2. ProjectConsumerModel.java

I have done the following configuration for the 'EventConsumerModel' class that is one consumer out of two consumers.
```

I have two consumer model classes:
1. EventConsumerModel. java
2. ProjectConsumerModel.java

```
I have done the following configuration for the 'EventConsumerModel' class that is one consumer out of two consumers.
```

I have two consumer model classes:
1. EventConsumerModel. java
2. ProjectConsumerModel.java

```
I have done the following configuration for the 'EventConsumerModel' class that is one consumer out of two consumers.
```

I have two consumer model classes:
1. EventConsumerModel. java
2. ProjectConsumerModel.java

```
I have done the following configuration for the 'EventConsumerModel' class that is one consumer out of two consumers.

application.yml:

#kafka details
spring.kafka.security.protocol=PLAINTEXT
spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers=localhost:9092
spring.kafka.properties.security.protocol=PLAINTEXT
spring.kafka.properties.spring.json.trusted.packages=*
spring.kafka.producer.key-serializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
spring.kafka.producer.value-serializer=org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer
spring.kafka.consumer.group-id=message-queue-consumers
spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset=earliest
spring.kafka.consumer.key-deserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
spring.kafka.consumer.value-deserializer=org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer
spring.kafka.consumer.properties.security.protocol=PLAINTEXT
spring.kafka.consumer.properties.spring.json.use.type.headers=false
spring.kafka.consumer.properties.spring.json.value.default.type=com.pearson.toc.javaapp.model.kafkaconsumermodels.EventConsumerModel
structure-api-topic=public.structure-api.skeleton.generation.v0-qa

The code for configuration class is as follow:

ReactiveKafkaConsumerConfig.java:

package com.pearson.toc.javaapp.config;

import java.util.Collections;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.kafka.KafkaProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.reactive.ReactiveKafkaConsumerTemplate;

import com.pearson.toc.javaapp.model.kafkaconsumermodels.ConsumerModel;

import reactor.kafka.receiver.ReceiverOptions;

@Configuration
public class ReactiveKafkaConsumerConfig {

    @Bean
    public ReceiverOptions<String, ConsumerModel> kafkaReceiverOptions(
            @Value(value = "${structure-api-topic}") String topic, KafkaProperties kafkaProperties) {
        ReceiverOptions<String, ConsumerModel> basicReceiverOptions = ReceiverOptions
                .create(kafkaProperties.buildConsumerProperties());
        return basicReceiverOptions.subscription(Collections.singletonList(topic));
    }

    @Bean
    public ReactiveKafkaConsumerTemplate<String, ConsumerModel> reactiveKafkaConsumerTemplate(
            ReceiverOptions<String, EventConsumerModel> kafkaReceiverOptions) {
        return new ReactiveKafkaConsumerTemplate<>(kafkaReceiverOptions);
    }
}

Now how to add configuration for the second model class which is : 'ProjectConsumerModel'

I tried with the following property to include both the consumer classes:
Now how to add configuration for the second model class which is : 'ProjectConsumerModel'
  
spring.kafka.consumer.properties.spring.json.value.default.type=com.pearson.toc.javaapp.model.kafkaconsumermodels.EventConsumerModel, com.pearson.toc.javaapp.model.kafkaconsumermodels.ProjecttConsumerModel

and it gave me 'invalid class error. Please let me know for any suggestion for the same. Thanks.
```